# Exiting interactive python3 session from script

Tags: python

I'd like my program to automatically exit if it detects an error when loading a file and parsing it (even when called from an interactive mode with -i). I've tried variations of `exit()` and `sys.exit()`, but nothing seems to be working. Instead of exiting the interactive session I get a stack trace. For example, if I have the file `test.py` that is the following:

```
import sys
sys.exit(0)
```

when I run `python3 -i test.py` I get the following result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    sys.exit()
SystemExit
>>>
```

and the session continues on, until I exit myself (using those exact lines subsequently work, just not when they're called from the script). What am I missing?

Comment: have you tried run the script without `-i`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling [os._exit()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os._exit) to exit directly, without throwing an exception

```
import os
os._exit(1)
```

Note that this will bypass all of the python shutdown logic. 
Hope it helps.